# Segmentation-free Handwritten Text Recognition with Keras

Tags: python, keras, ocr, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on an application for segmentation-free handwritten text recognition.
Therefore text lines are extracted from the input document that should then be recognized.

For development purpose I use the [IAM Handwriting Database](http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database). It provides text line images along with the corresponding ASCII text.

For the recognition I adapt the approaches found in the papers "[An End-to-End Trainable Neural Network for Image-based Sequence Recognition  and Its Application to Scene Text Recognition](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7801919/)" and "[Can We Build Language-independent OCR Using LSTM Networks?](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2505394)".

Basiacally, I use a bidirectional GRU architecture and a forward backward algorithm to align transcripts with the output of the neural network.

An image from the database looks like this:
[image]

The images are presented as 1D sequence of pixel values, more preceisely the images are first scaled to a height of 32 pixels.
The numpy array of the above image with the dimension of 597 *x* 32 has the shape of: (597, 32).
The numpy array, representing the overall training images of size *n*, has the shape of: (n, w, 32) where *w* would represent the variable width of the line images (for example 597).

The following code shows how the training images and the transcription are represented:

```
x_train = []
y_train = []
line_height_normalized = 32
for i in range(sample_size):
    transcription_train, image_train = self._get_next_sample()
    image_train = convert_to_grayscale(image_train)
    image_train = scale_y(image_train, line_height_normalized)
    image_train_patches = sklearn_image.extract_patches_2d(image_train, (line_height_normalized, 1))   
    image_train_patches = numpy.reshape(image_train_patches, (image_train_patches.shape[0], -1))
    x_train.append(image_train_patches)
    y_train.append(transcription_train)
```

I use *Keras* and the creation of the recurrent neural network and the CTC function are based on [this example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) .

```
charset = 68
number_of_memory_units = 512
time_steps = None
input_dimension = 32  # the height of a text line in pixel

# input shape see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3683
network_input = Input(name="input", shape=(time_steps, input_dimension))  

gru_layer_1 = GRU(number_of_memory_units, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  name='gru_layer_1')(network_input)
gru_layer_1_backwards = GRU(number_of_memory_units, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True,
                  kernel_initializer='he_normal',name='gru_layer_1_backwards')(network_input)
gru_layer_1_merged = add([gru_layer_1, gru_layer_1_backwards])
gru_layer_2 = GRU(number_of_memory_units, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  name='gru_layer_2')(gru_layer_1_merged)
gru_layer_2_backwards = GRU(number_of_memory_units, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  name='gru_layer_2_backwards')(gru_layer_1_merged)

output_layer = Dense(charset, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  name='dense_layer')(concatenate([gru_layer_2, gru_layer_2_backwards]))
prediction = Activation('softmax', name='output_to_ctc')(output_layer)

# create the ctc layer
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
max_line_length = 200  # see QUESTION 1
labels = Input(name='labels', shape=[max_line_length], dtype='float32')
loss_out = Lambda(RecurrentNeuralNetwork._ctc_function, name='ctc')(
        [prediction, labels, input_length, label_length])
model = Model(inputs=[network_input, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.02, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=5)
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda l_truth, l_prediction: prediction}, optimizer=sgd)
```

**Question 1**
In the example a *max_line_length* is used; as I read on the internet (but I  think I do not understand it quit well) a maximum line length is needed as the underlying CTC function needs to know how many tensors should be created.
What length is appropriate for an variable line length and how does this influence the recognition of unseen text lines?
Moreover what does the *input_length* variable and also the *label_length* variable exactly represent?

In the next step the network is trained:

```
batch_size = 1  
number_of_epochs = 4 

size = 32  # line height? see QUESTION 2
input_length = numpy.zeros([size, 1])
label_length = numpy.zeros([size, 1])
for epoch in range(number_of_epochs):
    for x_train_batch, y_train_batch in zip(x_train, y_train_labels):
        x_train_batch = numpy.reshape(x_train_batch, (1, len(x_train_batch), 32))
        inputs = {'input': x_train_batch, 'labels': numpy.array(y_train_batch),
                      'input_length': input_length, 'label_length': label_length}
        outputs = {'ctc': numpy.zeros([size])}  # dummy data for dummy loss function
        self.model.fit(x=inputs, y=outputs, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, shuffle=False)
        self.model.reset_states()
```

It is trained in batches of size 1 as the time steps are of variable length (the width of the text lines).
The transcription of a text line is represented by an numpy array *y_train_batch*; each character is number-encoded.
The transcription of the image example above looks like this:

```
[26 62 38 40 47 30 62 19 14 62 18 19 14 15 62 38 17 64 62 32  0  8 19 18 10  4 11 11 62  5 17 14 12]
```

**Question 2**
What does the *size* variable represent? Is it the dimension of the signle image patches and thus the features at each time step?

**Errors**
The errors which occure are the following:

- *Expected labels to have shape (200,) but got array with shape (1,)*
  Is it necessary to pad the labels array to contain 200 elements?

When I replace  the value of *max_line_length* with 1 the next error occurs:

- *All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(1, 597, 32), (33, 1), (32, 1), (32, 1)]*
  Is it necessary to reshape the other three arrays?
  I am not shure what is the "right" way to solve this and the possible next occuring errors?

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Thank you very much!

Comment: the maximum line length specifies the longest text that can be (1) recognized when decoding or (2) used as ground-truth for loss calculation per line. The length of 200 is enough for the IAM dataset you are using. Usually the CNN needs a fixed size input, therefore downsizing the images to a fixed height but an arbitrary width may cause problems. Try stretching the images to the desired size (I think it was 100x32 in the original CRNN implementation).
Highlevel overview CTC: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320868/understanding-connectionist-temporal-classification-ctc/331376#331376

Comment: @Harry Thank you very much for your comment! Just for clarification: does the maximum line length (in the official Keras example 'absolute_max_string_length', see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py#L470) represent the maximum number of characters of the labels or the maximum width of the line input images in pixel? Nonetheless, you are right with regard to stretching the images to a specific size, maybe it is even better to pad them so the images do not get distorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I wasn't able to explain this with the 600 chars available in the comment section, therefore I will do it by answering, however ignoring your Q2.

The code to the paper you mentioned can be found at: https://github.com/bgshih/crnn
It is a good starting point for handwritten text recognition. 
However, the CRNN implementation recognizes text on word-level, you want to do it on line-level, therefore you need larger input images, e.g. I used 800x64px and a maximum text length of 100.
And as already said, stretching images to the desired size does not work very well, in my experiments the accuracy increased when using padding (randomize positions a little bit ... it's an easy way to do data augmentation).

There is a relationship between the maximum text length L and the input image width W: the Neural Network (NN) downsizes the input image by a fixed scaling factor f: L=W/f (in my example: W=800px, L=100, f=8).
The illustrations attached shows the input image (800x64px) and the character probability matrix (probability for each of the 80 possible characters for each of the 100 time-steps).
The NN maps the input image to this character probability matrix which serves as input for the CTC. 
As there are L many time-steps in the matrix, there can be at most L many characters: this of course holds for decoding, but also loss calculation must align the ground truth text somehow with this matrix, and how should a text with L+1 characters be aligned with just L time-steps contained in the matrix!?
Note that inside the CTC calculation repeated characters (like in "piZZa") must be separated by a special character - therefore the possible text length decreases by 1 for each repetition.

[image: char probability matrix]

I think with this explanation you should be able to figure out how all those length-variables in your code are related to each other.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Your comment in combination with the paper "Connectionist Temporal Classification: Labelling Unsegmented Sequence Data with Recurrent Neural Networks" make the workings of a RNN and the CTC function very comprehensible.